# ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized. SQL Server Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, executescalar

I wrote this code to read the images stored in SQL Server database however I got this error:

> ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.

Since I already initialized the connection, I am not sure what the problem is.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = null;
try
{        
    myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Source; Initial Catalog=Database; user ID=Test; Password=Test");
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand ("SELECT imagedata FROM Database , myConnection");
    myConnection.Open();
    // Get the image from the database.   
    byte[] imagedata = (byte[])myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if (imagedata != null)
    {        
        return image;
    }
    else
    {      
        return null;
    }
}
finally
{       
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put both your `Select` statement and your connection in double quotes (`"`). i.e you didn't specify the `SqlCommand`'s `Connection` property actually. Change your `SqlCommand` from this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand ("SELECT imagedata FROM Database , myConnection");
```

To this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand ("SELECT imagedata FROM Database" , myConnection);
```

Or like this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT imagedata FROM Database");
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
```